# SMS functionality in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

In my Sencha Touch 2 application I have SMS, phone, email functionalities. These functionalities are working fine in Android, I am able to populate phone numbers, email addresses, and also body content visible to users. I have built it in Phonegap. All functionalities work fine except the SMS functionality, which does not work in iPad. Can anyone tell me why it is not working in iPad? How to achieve the SMS functionality for iPad?

Here is my code:

For SMS:

```
window.location = 'sms:' + '9035590355' + '?body=' + 'Hi hello';
```

For phone:

```
window.location = 'tel:' + '9035590355';
```

For email:

```
window.location = 'mailto:' + 'abcd@gmail.com' + '?subject=' + 'Update' + '&body=' + 'I sent you an email';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't work for iOS because the sms:// url scheme doesn't take body parameter for iOS.

See [iPhone URL Schemes](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#SMS)

or

See [Apple Developer : iPhone URL Schemes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference.pdf)

Also, I usually opens the SMS app like this

```
window.location.href = 'sms://';
```

Could you give it a try on iOS ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think iPad has an SMS functionality, even the 3G-enabled models...

Comment: No, but it has the Messages app which works with the SMS url scheme as well.

Answer (score -2):

Please try this

change:

```
window.location = 'sms:' + '9035590355' + '?body=' + 'Hi hello';
```

to:

```
window.location.href('sms:9035590355?body=Hi hello')
```

Hope this helps. ;)